# Python inherited class behaviour

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a question about python inherited class method, in the following code.

```
class B(object):
    def test(self):
        self.call()
    def call(self):
        print("Call from B")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.test()


from b import B

class C(B):
    def call(self):
        print("Call from C")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = C()
    c.test()
```

When I run this code, the result is

```
Call from C
```

The parent class method will call children's method. I want to know if it is an expected and stable behaviour? Because I also try the same logic in C++, it will print

```
Call from B
```

Comment: Is your question about whether Python has polymorphism? If so [the answer is yes it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724110/practical-example-of-polymorphism)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just wonder why there is a difference between C++ and python.

Comment: Works perfectly fine https://repl.it/repls/CoralComplicatedInstructions

Comment: "_why there is a difference between C++ and python_" Because they are 2 different languages and don't at all have to function exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to chepner's answer, this C++ code exhibits the exact same behaviour as you have in Python:

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
    void test() {
        call();
    }
    virtual void call() {
        std::cout << "Called from B" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C: public B {
public:
    void call() {
        std::cout << "Called from C" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
   C c;
   c.test();        // will print Called from C
   return 0;
}
```

If you come from C++ think that all members are public, and all methods virtual.

Comment: Thanks; I spent 20 minutes trying to write roughly this same thing ;) (only I used `C *c = new C();` in a mistaken belief that pointers were somehow necessary to invoke virtual method behavior.)

Comment: Thanks, I figure out why I didn't get the same result in C++, I forget using keyword virtual.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is expected. `c` is an instance of `C`, but since `C.test` is not defined, `c.test` resolves to `B.test`. However, the corresponding call to `self.call()` invokes `C.call` because the *runtime* type of `self` is `C`, not `B`, and `C.call` *is* defined. Think of all Python methods as being virtual methods.